# How to further my training without going to a gym?

Tags: strength-training, training

My current training sessions consist of the following :

- 10 elevated push ups (foot on an elevated platform)
- 25 squats
- 30 second planks

3 reps of the above, once every other day, totalling about 3-4 times a week.

The diet I'm following is the Paleo diet, which consist mostly of meats and vegetables and skipping on the carbs. I do have cheat days though, maybe 3 meals per week.

Sadly, I don't have the luxury or time to go to a gym. I'm starting to feel my training session is no longer taxing on my body, so I was hoping to make it harder.

What could I change/tweak in my training regime, aside from increasing the reps, so that it would be more effective?

My goals are to build my strength and lose body fat.

Comment: There's plenty of material out there for your use case. Google Freeletics or Yayog, for instance. See also [tag:bodyweight-exercises].

Comment: I would call repeating the entire sequence "3 sets of the above", rather than "3 reps of the above". That might help with communicating your workout.

Answer (score 1):

If you incorporate more standing and walking during the day you will burn more calories without having to go to the gym. <sub>[1]</sub>

Stand up at work (and at home). Try not to sit in an office chair or on the couch for hours on end.

To your list of exercises I would add two elements:

1. some kind of sit-ups or crunches to work the abdominal muscles
2. pull-ups or curls to work the biceps

Burpees are also a good full-body exercise that can burn a lot of calories. There are quite a few variations to work extra muscle groups. <sub>[2]</sub>

<sub>[1] http://www.livestrong.com/article/73916-calories-burned-standing-vs.-sitting/</sub>

<sub>[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burpee_%28exercise%29</sub>

Comment: Sadly I'm a programmer so the sitting is mostly not negotiable, however, I do take the bus and that adds quite a bit of walking in my everyday activities. 

I'm quite interested in pull-ups as well, but I don't have a raised bar.

Comment: Standing workstations are all the rage these days. I have been standing at my IT and programmer job for a couple of years now. Hang up a copy of the "Standing is Killing you" infographic near your cube or on the break room fridge...

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to make bodyweight exercises harder, and they generally involve decreasing leverage to making exercises harder, or doing unilateral exercises.

For example, using just your current plan.

- 10 uneven push ups (one hand higher than the other, alternating)
- 25 one-legged squats
- 30 second birddogs ( a plank with oneleg and the opposite arm raised).

Answer (score 0):

### It Can Always Get Harder

Elevate your feet higher.

Do more squats, deeper, in every set.

Plank for a minute.

Go through the entire sequence four times instead of three, trying to finish in the same amount of time.

Add lunges, burpees, or clapping push-ups to the sequence.

Do more of what you're doing, do what you're doing better, do a harder version of what you're doing, or do something different also. Those options almost always exist.

### Further reference

My preferred reference for making at-home exercise harder is Ross Enamait. Browse his [site](http://rosstraining.com/blog/) and [social media](http://instagram.com/rosstraining) to get a general sense of his methodology, and consider picking up [Never Gymless](http://www.rosstraining.com/nevergymless.html). The Primal Blueprint Fitness ebook also has some good ideas for designing Paleo-style home workouts.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to buy medicine ball. She will help you for new variants of exercises where other muscles start to act. Or  some dumbbells, weight most often help to increase strength.
To " lose body fat"  you'll need to burn more calories from taking over the day. Diet and training help, but i am not sure they are enough. What i mean? Best training for losing fats are aerobic exercise. If you don't have time for 30 min jogging, you can make sprints. I start with 3 x 100m every day. Then increase to 5 x 100 + jogging (20 min +) three times on week. If don't have time for this you can buy skipping rope. Also burning calories very good, don't take too much from your time like running, it's cheap and can skipping no matter what wheather is outside.
"Build my strength and lose body fat" its complex and hard, need some time and much personal destitution. Last year i lost 18 kg for 4 months doing what you now want. Don't give up and results will come.